# How to visualize log files from Hadoop?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, apache-flink, ambari

I am just a newbie in Big Data world, so I do not know how to build a dashboard application for visualizing data from log files in Hadoop. After searching around, I can think of some solution:

1/ Using Kafka to ingesting streaming data

2/ Stream data processing: Streaming Spark or Apache Flink

3/ Front-end --> Visualize data: using d3js

Am I missing something? Spark and Flink which one should I use?
I have a cluster of machines, I've installed Ambari, HDP 2.4.2, HDFS 2.7, YARN 2.7, Spark 1.6, Kafka.

If possible, could you guys show me some tutorials to build such a application like that? Any book or course?

Thank a lot.

P/s:
I have read the git book of databrick, but it's only mentioned spark. I also find some tutorials how to analyze using Flink, Elasticsearch and Kibana, but it's not mentioned about how to combine with Ambari Server, that where I got stuck

Comment: A simple Google search could have gave you some pointers .. https://databricks.gitbooks.io/databricks-spark-reference-applications/content/logs_analyzer/. This looks like a task best answered by the ELK stack, check out [Kibana](https://www.elastic.co/products/kibana) for visualizing and the [stack](https://www.elastic.co/products) in general. However, you haven't explicited your needs, so we can't help you much more than that. You need to think about your requirements before choosing any arbitrary technology.

Comment: I have read the git book of databrick, but it's only mentioned spark. I also find some tutorials how to analyze using Flink, Elasticsearch and Kibana, but it's not mentioned about how to combine with Ambari Server, that where I got stuck

Comment: Please adapt your question to explain what you found so far and your requirements, and aim it towards the Ambari community - if that's what stopping you currently.

Answer (score 0):

You may take a look at Ambari Log Search feature: https://github.com/abajwa-hw/logsearch-service which visualizes the logs.